# For/if loop with array multiplication using Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to use a for loop for a binary classification function using numpy. The problem that I am having is that the loop needs to continue until all values in Y are greater than 0 when multiplied by the updated value ak.

However, this loop is returning a value of ak that does ensure all values of Y are greater than 0. For example, the current output, [0,0,7], when multiplied by the fourth array in Y1, [-1,-1,0], is equal to 0.

What can I do to fix this issue? I have posted my code below. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np


def percep(a1, epochs, Y):
    sum = Y1.sum(axis=0)
    print(sum)
    ak=a1
    for k in range(1, epochs):
        if np.multiply(ak, Y).all() > 0:
            return(ak)
        else:
            rho = np.multiply(1/k, sum)
            ak = np.add(ak, rho) 
            return(ak)


a1 = np.array([0,0,0])
Y1 = np.array([ [1,1,1], [1,1,2], [1,2,2], [-1,-1,0], [-1, -1, 1], [-1, -2, 1]])
```

Comment: Why do you return in the else clause?  You haven't checked  for your condition/criteria after adding `rho`.  Your [mre] should show how you are calling `percep`.

Comment: I did not even think of that. Thank you for the tip, that is really helpful.